# Is it possible to have a struct with multiple JSON tags?

Tags: json, go, struct

I post a request to a server and get a reply in JSON format. I'm able to unmarshal it to a struct. Then I need to create a new JSON file with the same data but different JSON tags.

**Example:**

In the following code, I get `{"name":"Sam","age":20}` from a server and unmarshal it to the struct `Foo`:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

Then I need to change the tag `name` to `employee_name` and omit `age`:

```
type Bar struct {
    Name string `json:"employee_name"`
    Age  int    `json:"-"`
}
```

After that I send this modified data to another server.

I know I could just create a new `Bar` and copy all data into it, but there are a lot of fields. I was wondering if there is a way to attach multiple JSON tags like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string `json:"name" json:"employee_name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age" json:"-"`
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package only handles the `json` key in struct tags. If the `json` key is listed multiple times (as in your example), the first occurrence will be used (this is implemented in [`StructTag.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get)).

Note that this is an implementation restriction of the `encoding/json` package and not that of Go. One could easily create a similar JSON encoding package supporting either multiple tag keys (e.g. `json1`, `json2`) or multiple occurrences of the same key (as in your example).

Comment: As @icza suggested a different library could handle multiple tag keys and such a library does exist. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966527/500312

Answer (score 5):

What is possible though, with 2 identically laid out structs (namin, types and ordering of fields needs to match exactly) is to cast from one to the other. I would be very cautious of doing this though and make sure the 2nd type (bar in your example) is unexported to prevent from being used elsewhere.

https://play.golang.org/p/y8EH1U9_3jN

Comment: This was very helpful for me in working with nearly identical data from two different sources - thanks