# How to binding variable to multiple type json in GOLANG

Tags: json, go, coding-style

In Database convention of variable is full_name

In Postman convention of variable is fullName

```
type Person struct {
    FullName string `json:"fullName"`
}
```

but I want to Unmarshal with convention full_name

Sorry my English beacuse English is not my native language

Comment: See [Is it possible to have a struct with multiple JSON tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37118263/5291015)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
type Person struct {
    Fullname string `json:"fullname"`
    AmoumtRefund string `json:"amount_refund"`
}
```

FOR EXAMPLE

```
type User struct {
    Id            string                   `json:"user_id,omitempty"`
    Email         string                   `json:"email,omitempty"`
    EmailVerified *bool                    `json:"email_verified,omitempty"`
    GivenName     string                   `json:"given_name,omitempty"`
    FamilyName    string                   `json:"family_name,omitempty"`
    Name          string                   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Nickname      string                   `json:"nickname,omitempty"`
    Username      string                   `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Subject       string                   `json:"sub,omitempty"`
    Blocked       *bool                    `json:"blocked,omitempty"`
}
```