# Input field validation with two possible names

Tags: python, go

I'm migrating an API that was originally written in Python.
The Python API allows you to send your request as camelCase or snake_case like this:

This is allowed

```json
{
    "someInput": "nice"
}
```

This is allowed

```json
{
    "some_input": "nice"
}
```

This is done using a great Python library: Pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

def to_camel(string):
    words = string.split('_')
    return words[0] + ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in words[1:])

class InputModel(BaseModel):
    some_input: str

    class Config:
        alias_generator = to_camel
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

This allows to create an InputModel by alias (someInput) or by field name (some_input).
I want to do the same or equivalent in Go. I'm using Gin:

```golang
func Routes(router *gin.Engine) {
    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    {
        v1.POST("/shipments", controllers.ShipmentCreator)
    }
}

func ShipmentCreator(ctx *gin.Context) {
    ResponseController := new(internal.OutputModel)
    var body domain.ShipmentsInputModel
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&body); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    validate := validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(body)
    if err != nil {
        var validationErrors validator.ValidationErrors
        errors.As(err, &validationErrors)
        for _, validationError := range validationErrors {
            ResponseController.AddError(internal.ErrorsModel{
                Parameter: validationError.Field(),
                Message:   validationError.Error(),
            })
        }
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, ResponseController)
        return
    }
```

My input struct looks something like this:

```golang
type ShipmentsInputModel struct {
    LotId   string   `json:"lotId" tag:"lot_id" alias:"lot_id" validate:"required"`
}
```

This does not work when my input is:

```json
{
   "lot_id": "someLotId"
}
```

It returns:

```
"message": "Key: 'ShipmentsInputModel.LotId' Error:Field validation for 'LotId' failed on the 'required' tag",
```

How can I accept both camelCase and snake_case?

Comment: "I want to do the same or equivalent in Go" Not really. You don't want to do this in Python in the first place. This is crappy API design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang multiple json tag names for one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809137/golang-multiple-json-tag-names-for-one-field)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat
 Not quite, this one is an equivalent question: [Is it possible to have a struct with multiple JSON tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118263/is-it-possible-to-have-a-struct-with-multiple-json-tags) but the answers are not as helpful for my case as the one that I accepted here.

Comment: @Volker I'm just migrating the API I can't add/remove behavior because the python version is being used already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, you cannot provide two JSON tags together for a single struct field. JSON tags are specified using a single string, and they are used to define how a field should be marshaled (serialized to JSON) or unmarshaled (deserialized from JSON). You cannot specify multiple tags for a single field within a struct directly.

If you need to support both CamelCase and SnakeCase in your JSON output, you would typically have to choose one consistent naming convention for your struct fields and then use appropriate JSON tags for all the fields.

There's a neat way of doing this. I hope this helps.

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
    )
    
    type ShipmentsInputModel struct {
        LotID
    }
    
    type LotID struct {
        LotId  string `json:"lotId,omitempty"`
        Lot_ID string `json:"lot_id,omitempty"`
    }
    
    func (s *ShipmentsInputModel) setLodID(id string) {
        s.LotId = id
        s.Lot_ID = id
    }
    
    func main() {
        shipment := ShipmentsInputModel{}
        shipment.setLodID("someLotID")
    
        // Convert struct to JSON
        jsonData, err := json.Marshal(shipment)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            return
        }
        // prints: {"lotId":"someLotID","lot_id":"someLotID"}
        fmt.Println(string(jsonData))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a great starting point. I just have to make one required if the other is not present. But I sincerely will try to make the API clients drop the use of snake_case

Answer (score 3):

There is actually one way to validate input with two possible names in the Gin with a binding tag in the struct filed tag, which allows you to specify multiple keys for the same field, As an example, see this below example:

```
type ShipmentsInputModel struct {
LotId string `json:"lotId" json:"lot_id" binding:"required,lotId|lot_id"`
}
```

To read more about validation and binding read in this https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/binding-and-validation/

Comment: The `binding` tag isn't even used to unmarshal the data its used for the validation after the `json` package has already done its work. This solution simply won't work...

Comment: by adding two JSON tag it will simply works

Comment: Are you **testing** this code before you post it as an answer? That won't work either